# ¿Por qué el menú hamburguesa se despliega en el lado contrario?

Tags: menú, nav

lo que quiero es que el menú hamburguesa se despliegue justo debajo de donde se encuentra el icono del menú, es decir, a la derecha. Sin embargo, lo que ocurre es que se despliega en el lado izquierdo de la pantalla, es decir, debajo del logo y no del icono de menú. Por favor, ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#menú" class="lanzador-menu" id="enlace-menu"><img src="icono.jpg"></a>

<div id="menú" class="navegación">
        <ul>
            
            <li><a href="" class="enlace">El espacio</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="enlace">Productos</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="enlace">Ofertas</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="enlace">Reservas</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="enlace">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.navegación a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f5f0ed;
    }

.lanzador-menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 27px;
    right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
var lanzador = "#enlace-menu";

var desplegable = "#menú";

var despliegaClase = "menu-desplegado";
function nav(){
    var lanz = document.querySelector(lanzador);    
    lanz.addEventListener("click", despliegaMenu, false);
}

function despliegaMenu(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var despl = document.querySelector(desplegable);
    despl.classList.toggle(despliegaClase);
}

document.querySelector("html").classList.add("js");

nav();
```

Comment: Cuando estés programando, evita siempre los acentos y tildes en las palabras clave (nombres de clases, variables...). Dan más problemas de lo que ayudan

Answer (score 0):

Usa posicionamiento absoluto:

```js
function clickMenu(){
  document.getElementById('menú')
          .classList
          .toggle('visible');
}
```

```css
ul{
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.navegación a{
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f5f0ed;
}

.lanzador-menu{
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#menú:not(.visible){ display: none }
#menú.visible{ 
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  top: 70px;
  right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#menú"
   id="enlace-menu"
   class="lanzador-menu"
   onclick="clickMenu()"   
>☰</a>

<div id="menú" class="navegación">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="" class="enlace">El espacio</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="enlace">Productos</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="enlace">Ofertas</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="enlace">Reservas</a></li>
            <li><a href="" class="enlace">Contacto</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```